# Не может найти и загрузить main class. Win10

Tags: java

[image: Фрагмент кода] 
Полагаю, что это один из самых распространенных вопросов от начинающих. Я учусь по учебнику с сайта [ProgLang](http://proglang.su/java/installation-and-configuration-on-a-pc). 
[image: Просили изменить среду] 
 На другом сайте, когда пришлось искать решение, просили добавить PATH и CLASSPATH, который пришлось удалить, что с ним, что без него, ничего не меняется.
[image: На другом сайте, когда пришлось искать решение, просили добавить PATH и CLASSPATH, который пришлось удалить, что с ним, что без него, ничего не меняется] 
Если с командой javac получилось разобраться, то почему командная строка не выводит результат -- нет.

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать? Если запустить файл, то это `java -jar file.jar`

Comment: У вас в каталоге `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MyJava` есть файл `MyFirstJavaProgram.class`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да.

Comment: @ArchDemon, я пытаюсь вывести в консоль надпись "Hello, World". Можете объяснить, что означает java -jar file.jar?

Comment: А директиву `package` вы в исходном коде этого класса не используете ли?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, и с ней, и без нее выдается ошибка.

Comment: Нужно указать класспасс `java -cp . MyFirstJavaProgram`

Comment: @talex рабочий каталог является значением CLASSPATH по умолчанию, так что не нужно, если вообще `-cp` не указывать.